# What's the "accent color"?

Tags: android, material-design

Either my English is not good enough or I just do not get it, but could anybody please explain to me what the "accent color" is and where it is used?

---

My question originated from the fact that I couldn't find a real description of when and how that color is used. Had I scrolled [further down](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html), I'd have found that description, too.

Sorry to interrupt, thanks for pointing me to it everybody.

Comment: Updated link: https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-theme-creation

Comment: I think term "Accent color" originates from the Microsoft world. Seen it used there quite often.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You got good example in [Material Design docs](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html) -> your palettes are shown in section "[UI color application](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-ui-color-application)" - with blue colors being primary and pink being used for accents.

Here is what it means in practice (also FAB would most likely use pink background color)

[image]

Comment: Oh man - should have scrolled down a bit. I was already reading the page you linked...

Comment: Excuse me, and where is this accent color used by default?

Comment: I still don't get it. Would anyone care to tell me, where I can use color="accent" (I know it will work with mat-button, but not with div elements). And what are other values I can use instead of accent? Only primary and secondary?

Comment: You can think of accent = highlighted. For example, active tab, focused input, etc. It is a color used to draw attention.

Comment: Links broken, not sure where the new ones are (or if this pictured UI is any more available)

Answer (score 30):

Quoting from http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2014/08/material-design-in-2014-google-io-app.html:

> In material design, UI element color palettes generally consist of one primary and one accent color.
>   The accent color is used more subtly throughout the app, to call attention to key elements. The resulting juxtaposition of a tamer primary color and a brighter accent, gives apps a bold, colorful look without overwhelming the app’s actual content.

Answer (score 19):

Accent color is also known as Secondary color.

It is used for:

- Buttons
- Floating action buttons
- Selection controls, like sliders and switches
- Highlighting selected text
- Progress bars
- Links and headlines