# How to change progress bar progress color?

Tags: android, styles, android-progressbar

I created this progress bar for my app, but I cant get that yellow orangy color that appears to change to something like red or blue.

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="250sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progress="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:max="3"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

above is my progress bar xml code.

Any help guys? :)

Thanks so much in advance! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android change Horizonal Progress bar color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745814/android-change-horizonal-progress-bar-color)

Answer (score 54):

If android version is 5.0 and above you just need to set

```
android:indeterminateTint="@color/BLACK"
android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
```

For lower version I use this

```
mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources()
.getColor(R.color.primary_color),PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Answer (score 13):

Create a new XML file in your drawable folder called something like `custom_progress_bar.xml` and paste this there:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#000000" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And in your `<ProgressBar>` add this attribute:

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar"
```

Change the 2 colors to your own preference. I put `#FFFFFF` and `#000000` which are white and black.

Comment: Dear Vuko,
        
           Your method worked amazingly! Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I want to do the same programmatically. In my case, I want to change the progress color from code using hex value without changing the background color. Need help.

Comment: What comes to my mind is that you can create the same drawable with a different color, and replace the progress drawable from code. If you need to dynamically choose the color (it ain't always the same), then it's harder, If I think of  a solution I'll let you know :D @NavjotBedi

Answer (score 6):

Go to your **styles.xml** and change the *colorAccent* value from your base application theme e.g.
`<item name="colorAccent">{COLOR}</item>`
I am using minSdkVersion 15 and it worked for me.

Comment: This is only a good solution if you don't mind that EVERYWHERE your colors might change to this. `ColorAccent` is a very important attribute and should be changed with caution. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021198/whats-the-accent-color)

Comment: It might **look** easier than my solution to add just this one line people, but it come with some caveats. Beware before using it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change the ProgressBar color, **not by drawable**, you can use this style as theme for the ProgressBar

```
<style name="ProgressBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white_primary</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

If `android:indeterminateTint` doesn't work, try this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:progressTint="@color/Red" <--------------------------
    android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/Blue" <---------------
    android:layout_width="250sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progress="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
    android:max="3"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this and add you custom color

```
Progressbar mBar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
mBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#80DAEB"),
            android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

For future references:

For API 21+ we can use directly in the XML:

```
android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/white"
```

Answer (score 1):

set theme in style.xml like this

```
 <style name="ProgressBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/dark_blue</item>
</style>
```

then use this style as "theme" in progressBar like this,

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:theme="@style/ProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="440dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/splashTitle"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.493"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/splashTitle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/splashTitle" />
```

Happy coding