# I can't set the color of an Android switch in Xamarin.Forms with Styles

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using the following XML to try and change the colors of a switch in my Xamarin forms application. However nothing changes. 
 Can anyone give me any advice on what I might be doing wrong:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
</style>
<!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">      
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">45dp</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.Switch" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF0000</item>
 </style>
```

Here's a clip from MainActivity.cs

```
 [Activity(Label = "Japanese", Icon = "@drawable/Icon120", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, 
          ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
          ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
```

As this didn't work I tried some changes but same problem in that it doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <item name="segmentedControlOptionStyle">@style/SegmentedControlOption</item>
        <item name="switchStyle">@style/SwitchCompat</item>
    </style>
</resources>

<style name="SwitchCompat" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FFFF00</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00FFFF</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF00FF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set a style, by passing it to the MainActivity? Like explained here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70907/forms-switch-doesnt-look-like-i-expected-on-android

Comment: I updated the question to show MainActivity

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46157966/when-toggled-and-disabled-android-switch-is-all-greyed-out/46159563#46159563

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MyTheme.Switch` style does not automatically get applied to all switches. If the `colorAccent` is moved inside `MyTheme.Base`, then it can change the tint color (note `colorAccent` applies to other widgets as well):

```xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
</style>
<!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">      
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">45dp</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

[image]

A custom renderer will allow more control over the styling. The following custom renderer can be used to reference your custom style (note you'll want to replace `PanDemo.Droid` with your namespace).

```cs
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(
    typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Switch), 
    typeof(PanDemo.Droid.CustomSwitchRenderer))]

namespace PanDemo.Droid
{
    public class CustomSwitchRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.SwitchRenderer
    {
        public CustomSwitchRenderer(Android.Content.Context context)
            : base(context) { }

        protected override Android.Widget.Switch CreateNativeControl()
        {
            return new Android.Widget.Switch(
                new Android.Views.ContextThemeWrapper(
                    this.Context, 
                    Resource.Style.MyTheme_Switch /* <- Custom Switch Style */));
        }
    }
}
```

Then just modify your custom style as necessary, for example:

```xml
<style name="MyTheme.Switch" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch">
    <item name="colorAccent">#008000</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to just apply the red color to switches? I looked at custom renderers before but only have the need for just the switch color and I had problems trying to do that.

Comment: @Alan2, I added a sample custom renderer that may meet your needs

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio check your android project and find this file:

`Resources -> values -> styles.xaml`

There you can change the wanted color in this item:

```
<item name="colorAccent">#3c94c7</item>
```

This will change "colorAccent" from your Android theme.

You cant find more about the colorAccent in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021198/whats-the-accent-color/31021281)